# How to wait for WCF to release the port?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows service that is using WCF to communicate with the gui. Unfortunately when I want to restart service from the gui (to reload config) I get the message:

> There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:1111

I'm restarting the service using fallowing code:

```
        if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            sc.Stop();
            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            sc.Start();
        }
```

The problem is that service controller have already status on stopped and WCF still didn't release the port. How can i wait for this to happen?

Comment: Was the port left in TIME_WAIT?

Comment: It's a tcp connection so probably the answer is yes. The port is not blocked for long - just few seconds and I can run the service again).

Comment: What did you do in your OnStop method? Please show the code.

Comment: Nothing - just writing to the eventlog. Entire WCF hosting part is placed in another class with IDisposable implemented. I've silently hoped ServiceHost will be collected by garbage collector (after executing close() method in GC). Explicitly running Dispose() didn't make any difference.

Comment: You may have just answered your question. Whatever you do in OnStart, you need to undo in OnStop.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with the same issue.  In the OnStop method I call the ServiceHost's Close() method and then set the service host itself to null.

So far, just doing that has made the issue go away... so far.